# Capture a date from an unknow string length

Tags: php, parsing, trim

I have a string say "ETS 13-JUN-13sf342356". I am able to parse out the date with some simple ltrim and rtrim functions. My question is if I don't know what is before or after or how long the string is can I still capture this date? Some more examples are:

- "JoeR13JUN134092883094"
- "CC13-JUN-13tl320994"
- "3425313-JUN-13tl345550"

Is there a single function that will always capture the (in this case) 13-JUN-13 date out of these strings?

Comment: No, you will need to write one yourself. You'll almost certainly need to use regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following with your input and worked for that.  Seems long but give it a try:

```
([0-9]{2})(\-[A-Z]+|[A-Z]+)(\-[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{2})
```

Comment: preg_match('/([0-9]{2})(\-[A-Z]+|[A-Z]+)(\-[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{2})/', $test , $matches);
Worked great thanks!